# Can I perform an action like clicking on the server side?

Tags: javascript, web, hyperlink

I am quite new to web development and I have some trouble figuring out how to create a bot that clicks for me.

I have a website with a bunch of links that I want to click. I can easily identify them by building a web scraper. I want to create a bot that clicks the links every day at 12:00 AM without my intervention.

Since I won't always be online at the time, I wish to know if there is a way I can create a bot and host it, that can visit the site, authenticate, and do the clicking. All handled by the bot on the server without me having to open any browser tab.

In your reply, you can assume I am going to code the bot in Javascript or Python.

Thanks.

Comment: take a look at `selenium` https://www.selenium.dev/

Comment: If you use Nodejs you can use Puppeteer.

Comment: I know about both solutions. However my worry is whether the process can be carried out on a server without my intervention. Thanks for your  answers.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a server-side (headless) API to control a web browser.

Some examples include `puppeteer`, in NodeJS and `selenium` in Python.

On their GitHub, you have some quick and basic examples regarding how to use the tool: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer.

You can install it using `npm`. A basic example would be:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest thing you can do is install `selenium IDE` into your browser.

save all the `side` files with your tests directly from the browser extension

Once you did that copy it on your server and install `command-line-runner`
https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/command-line-runner

Then you can setup your cron to launch the tests